# Limpiar /Resetear varios formularios

Tags: html, html5

En mi codigo tengo 2 formularios que una vez que se envian quisiera que se limpiaran los datos anteriores en cada uno de ellos. Actualmente solo "limpia" el dato de busqueda del formulario "fe"

```
<div id="actualiza">
<form name="fe" action="" method="post">
    <table border="2">
        <tbody><tr><td>Nombre de Usuario</td>
        <td><input name="txtbus" type="text"></td>
        <td><input name="btn1" value="Buscar" type="submit" onsubmit="this.reset()"></td></tr>
</form>     
</tbody></table>

<form name='contacto' method="POST" action="">
         <div><etiqueta>Nombre de Usuario:</etiqueta><input type='text' id="usuario" name="usuario" value='<?php echo $row['nombre_usuario']?>'></div>
        <div><etiqueta>Empleado:</etiqueta><input type='text' id="nombre" name="nombre" value='<?php echo $row['nombre']?>'></div>
<input name="btn2" value="Aceptar" type="submit" onsubmit="this.reset()">
```

Comment: ¿En qué momento quieres que se limpien las formas?

Comment: luego de enviar los datos

Comment: porque una vez que le doy "Aceptar", y necesito "Buscar" otro registro, me aparecen los datos del registro anterior

Comment: Me imagino que tienes código JS que se ejecuta al dar clic en submit, puedes intentar poner ahí la función de resetear la forma donde se hizo submit

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero que percibo del código de ejemplo que nos planteas son un par de errores de marcado: El `div` *actualiza* no se cierra, el segundo form no tiene etiqueta de cierre tampoco, cierras el `table` después del `form`...

Dejando esos asuntos de lado (que pueden confundir al navegador que interpreta ese `HTML`) el evento `onsubmit` debiera ir en el `form` y no en el `input[type='submit']`.

Por ejemplo, de esta forma:

```
<div id="actualiza">
<form name="fe" action="" method="post" onsubmit="this.reset()">
    <table border="2">
        <tbody><tr><td>Nombre de Usuario</td>
        <td><input name="txtbus" type="text"></td>
        <td><input name="btn1" value="Buscar" type="submit" ></td></tr>
</tbody></table>
</form>     

<form name='contacto' method="POST" action="" onsubmit="this.reset()">
         <div><etiqueta>Nombre de Usuario:</etiqueta><input type='text' id="usuario" name="usuario" value='<?php echo $row['nombre_usuario']?>'></div>
        <div><etiqueta>Empleado:</etiqueta><input type='text' id="nombre" name="nombre" value='<?php echo $row['nombre']?>'></div>
<input name="btn2" value="Aceptar" type="submit">
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: gracias por responder, en primer termino el codigo es mucho mas largo y lo resumi en la parte que respecta a la pregunta y es posible que no haya cerrado algunas etiquetas; en cuanto al evento  onsubmit, si lo coloco en el form "fe" al darle click lo "limpia" y no realiza la busqueda

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema radica en que estás haciendo un "`<?php echo $row['nombre_usuario']?>`" en el value del input por ende nunca se va a "resetear"

Cada vez que un formulario realiza un submit se reinician los valores.

Comment: si pero el valor de [$row['nombre_usuario']] proviene de la busqueda por codigo que se introduce en el primer formulario. lo que quiero es que una vez se consulte y actualicen los campos de ese registro, al llamar una nueva consulta no muestre el formulario con los datos anteriores.